# Getting a basic screen for app store, and not showing further updates

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore

I don't know how to fix this, it is a friend's 2017 Macbook Air running High Sierra, thought I would update it to Big Sur finally.

There is an issue with my mac running High Sierra. Now that I need to update, it is showing this.

[image]

Comment: Server-side problem, affects all Macs running 10.11–10.13. Not your fault but there’s nothing you can do. Functionality still works, it’s all just a bit ugly.

Comment: If you want to update the OS itself, then you don't actually need that page; you'll find Big Sur on the main Featured page. The other pages seem to work OK.